# How do I link OAuth2 to an already create email and password account?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

How I plan for this system to work is: register an account with email/password first, and then authorize an Oauth2 app in settings somewhere. How could I bind the Oauth2 service with the email/password account?

I couldn't find how to do this anywhere in any documentation with the service, as well as other sources online.